# Get each level parent category name

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to be able to display parent category name on list like below

What would like example out put

Table

```
FID     Name                                Action

54      CodeIgniter // Parent               Edit

59      CodeIgniter > General // Parent     Edit

60      CodeIgniter > General > News        Edit

63      CodeIgniter > General > Lounge      Edit

65      CodeIgniter > Using CodeIgniter     Edit

64      PHP
```

> **Currently I can only make it show**

```
Table 

FID     Name                                Action

54      CodeIgniter // Parent               Edit

59      General  // Parent                  Edit

60      General > News                      Edit

63      General > Lounge                    Edit

65      CodeIgniter > Using CodeIgniter     Edit

64      PHP
```

> **Question** Using the model function below how can I display parents name of sub category on each level

Model function

```
public function get_parent_name($pid) {
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('forum');
    $this->db->where('fid', $pid);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row()->name . ' > ';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Controller

```
<?php

class Category extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('admin/forum/forum_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $results = $this->forum_model->getcategories();

        $data['categories'] = $this->getcategoriesdata($results);

        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $this->load->view('template/forums/category_view', $data);
    }

    public function getcategoriesdata($results = array(), $pid = 0) {
        $display = '';

        foreach ($results as $result) { 

            if ($result['pid'] != $pid) {
                continue;
            }

            $display .= '<tr>';
            $display .= '<td  class="text-center">' . $result['fid'] . '</td>';
            $display .= '<td>' . $this->get_parent_name($result['pid']) . $result['name'] . '</td>';
            $display .= '<td  class="text-center">' . anchor('admin/category/edit' .'/'. $result['fid'], 'Edit') . '</td>';
            $display .= '</tr>';

            $display .= $this->getcategoriesdata($results, $result['fid']);
        }

        return $display;
    } 

    public function get_parent_name($pid) {
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->from('forum');
        $this->db->where('fid', $pid);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row()->name . ' > ';
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code in my Laptop. I have a good solution & it's worked. Just you can re call your `get_parent_name($pid)` method in your controller like that.

```
return $this->get_parent_name($query->row()->pid).$query->row()->name . ' > ';
```

And `$this->db->select('*');` instead `$this->db->select('name');`

So, Final code is :

```
public function get_parent_name($pid) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('forum');
    $this->db->where('fid', $pid);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $this->get_parent_name($query->row()->pid).$query->row()->name . ' > ';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```